# SQL Insert Missing Rows with no Match

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have an issue where I currently have 1 table which is filled with data and is rolled up by week, unfortunately the table the data comes from does not have an entry for each person for each week (many reasons why), therefore I would like to create a table based on result from 1st temp table against a week check temp table

This is results from first select into temp table

Table 1

```
Logger Name AGENT   ManagerName AGENT_ID    Week    Logs    MonthID
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         42      25      179
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         44      120     180
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         45      11      180
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         48      41      181
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         49      223     181
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         50      92      181
```

Table 2 (Temp Weeks) to check against

```
Week    Month
40      179
41      179
42      179
43      179
44      180
45      180
46      180
47      180
48      181
49      181
50      181
```

End Table Desired Result ( has added in data for missing Weeks from Table 1 with 0 Value for Logs

```
Logger Name AGENT   ManagerName AGENT_ID    Week    Logs    MonthID         
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         40      0       179
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         41      0       179
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         42      25      179
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         43      0       179
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         44      120     180
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         45      11      180
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         46      0       180
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         47      0       180
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         48      41      181
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         49      223     181
Logger1     Agent1  Manager1    ID1         50      92      181
```

Can anyone help me on creating a query to create this table, Table 1 will have many Agents in it but Log name will be constant.

The Week Check temp table may not be required It was just a thought I had of cheking against somehow and if month and Week not present in table 1 then add!

Comment: Calendar table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option. Query finds all combinations of agents and weeks. And removes weeks which already exists in first table. Then inserts remaing data

```
declare @t table ([Logger Name] varchar(100), AGENT varchar(100), ManagerName varchar(100), AGENT_ID varchar(100), Week int, Logs int, MonthID int)
insert into @t
values ('Logger1', 'Agent1', 'Manager1', 'ID1', 42, 25, 179)
    , ('Logger1', 'Agent1', 'Manager1', 'ID1', 44, 120, 180)
    , ('Logger1', 'Agent1', 'Manager1', 'ID1', 45, 11, 180)
    , ('Logger1', 'Agent1', 'Manager1', 'ID1', 48, 41, 181)
    , ('Logger1', 'Agent1', 'Manager1', 'ID1', 49, 223, 181)
    , ('Logger1', 'Agent1', 'Manager1', 'ID1', 50, 92, 181)

declare @q table (Week int, Month int)
insert into @q
values (40, 179), (41, 179)
    , (42, 179), (43, 179), (44, 180)
    , (45, 180), (46, 180), (47, 180)
    , (48, 181), (49, 181), (50, 181)

insert into @t
select
    distinct t.[Logger Name], t.AGENT, t.ManagerName, t.AGENT_ID, q.Week, 0, q.Month
from
    @t t
    cross join @q q
where
    not exists (
        select 1
        from
            @t f
        where
            f.AGENT = t.AGENT
            and f.Week = q.Week
            and f.MonthID = q.Month
    )

select * from @t
order by AGENT, Week
```

Comment: Cheers that was a fast response and it works great, I am still relatively new so am learning and can kinda follow and adapt this.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the rows with `cross join`, then add the additional data using `left join`:

```
select l.*, w.*,
       coalesce(t1.logs, 0) as logs
from (select distinct LoggerName, Agent, ManagerName, AgentId
      from table1
     ) l cross join
     tempweeks w left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.LoggerName = l.LoggerName and t1.Agent = l.Agent and
        t1.ManagerName = l.ManagerName and t1.AgentId = l.AgentId and
        t1.week = w.week and t1.monthid = w.weekid;
```

You can easily turn this into an insert, by doing something like:

```
insert into table1 ( . . . )
    select . . ., 0 as logs
    from (select distinct LoggerName, Agent, ManagerName, AgentId
          from table1
         ) l cross join
         tempweeks w left join
         table1 t1
         on t1.LoggerName = l.LoggerName and t1.Agent = l.Agent and
            t1.ManagerName = l.ManagerName and t1.AgentId = l.AgentId and
            t1.week = w.week and t1.monthid = w.weekid
    where t1.LoggerName is null;
```

Comment: I'm sure this also works, but not had chance to test yet but will when get chance thanks